# Xcode: Module 'MarketingCloudSDK' has no member named 'sharedInstance' error after updating the DSK to 8.0.12

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I updated the MarketingCloudSDK to 8.0.12 (was 7.5.0) by removing the pods and installing it as Swift Packages.

After that I get this error: Module 'MarketingCloudSDK' has no member named 'sharedInstance'.

I tried to search for an alternative name like "shared" but nothing worked. Anyone else experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Some quick Googling found that they have restructured their SDK’s API in v8.0 and have a migration guide: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-migration.html